# Checking for a one-to-one correlation of data with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have data containing two columns I am interested in. Ideally, the data in these is always in matching sets like this:

```
A 1
A 1
B 2 
B 2
C 3
C 3
C 3
```

However, there might be bad data where the same value in one column has different values in the other column, like this:

```
D 4 
D 5
```

or:

```
E 6
F 6
```

How do I isolate these bad rows, or at least show that some of them exist?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: What is the primary key in your data?

Comment: It's a different column. And actually, my data is spread over multiple tables -- the example is very simplified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <> t.col2);
```

If you just want the `col1` values that have non-matches, you can use aggregation:

```
select col1, min(col2), max(col2)
from t
group by col1
having min(col2) <> max(col2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `MIN` and `MAX` as analytic functions we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, MIN(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS min_col2,
                MAX(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) AS max_col2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT col1, col2
FROM cte
WHERE min_col2 <> max_col2;
```

The above approach, while seemingly verbose, would return all offending rows.